# Error: "headers" option needs to be an dictionary style

Tags: http, ionic-framework, ionic-native, cordova-plugin-advanced-http, ionic-native-http

I am trying to get a `blob` image from the backend and I am using `native HTTP` in the ionic 4 app.

Implementation as shown below:

```
import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

constructor(private nativeHttp: HTTP) {}

getAttachmentWithNativeHttp(url: string, parameters?: any): Observable<any> {
    url = url + this.commonService.getQueryString(parameters);
    var headers = this.getHeaders('GET', url);
    this.nativeHttp.clearCookies();
    this.nativeHttp.setServerTrustMode('nocheck');
    const reqOptions: any = {
      method: 'get',
      responseType: 'blob' as 'blob',
      headers: headers
    }
    return from(this.nativeHttp.sendRequest(url, reqOptions)).pipe(
      finalize(() => { if (toIntercept) this.setProgressDialogVisibility(false) })
    )
  }
```

[image: I need these headers]

the `sendRequest()` allows me to pass the `responseType` parameter. I also tried using `get()` but I whenever I make the request call, I am getting this error:

[image: Error Message]

I am missing something with `headers` or do I need to send a `responseType` in another way to get the blob image?

Comment: Not the right way to go about doing it, but params = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(params)) unblocked me. Could probably be a bug